# NullPointerException on QueryDSL where clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Using [Query DSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) with hibernate (Spring Data JPA) to build a query like so

```
    if( bankId != null ){
        query.where(
            coopMember.personId.bankAccountId.isNotNull().and(
            coopMember.personId.bankAccountId.bankBranch.bankId.eq(bankId))
        );
    }

    return query.fetch();
```

The logic here is simple: if there is a bank account associated with a person, filter the results by bank id.

The `BankAccount` entity has a `BankBranch` which holds `bankId` integer value. A `CoopMember` entity may or may not have a `BankAccount`

Problem is when the above QueryDSL query is executed, a `NullPointerException` is thrown, even if a not null check is in place.

## Update

On changing the logic to following the same error is thrown. I wonder why `bankBranch` cannot be "null-checked":

```
    if( bankId != null ){
        query.where(
                coopMember.personId.bankAccountId.isNotNull().and(
                        coopMember.personId.bankAccountId.bankBranch.isNotNull())
        );
    }
```

Following stacktrace thrown:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at re.iprocu.repository.impl.MemberRepositoryImpl.findMembersByPaymentModes(MemberRepositoryImpl.java:306) ~[classes/:na]
>       at re.iprocu.repository.impl.MemberRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6aae55eb.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at re.iprocu.repository.impl.MemberRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8dc2283d.findMembersByPaymentModes() ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:520) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:495) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy189.findMembersByPaymentModes(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at re.iprocu.service.impl.PaymentPeriodServiceBean.findMemberPaymentModeDetails(PaymentPeriodServiceBean.java:183) ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.findMemberPaymentModeDetails(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at re.iprocu.api.PaymentPeriodController.memberPaymentsByPaymentMode(PaymentPeriodController.java:299) ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at re.iprocu.utils.jwt.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:67) [classes/:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104) [undertow-servlet-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:332) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-1.4.21.Final.jar:1.4.21.Final]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]

Comment: not null check is only for `bankId` and `bankAccountId` what about if `coopMember` is `null` or  `personId` is `null` ? u can find by just using debugger

Comment: @mjsoft: `coopMember` and `personId` are nt null fields

Comment: Can you highlight the code on row 306 of MemberRepositoryImpl.findMembersByPaymentModes(MemberRepositoryImpl.java

Comment: When posting this stack trace, you assumed that its entirety is going to be relevant to answer your question, right? :-)

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, why asking?

Comment: @Yunus Einsteinium why you are not using debugger ..? use debugger on that line you will find  one of the field  is `null` .

Comment: @YunusEinsteinium: I was being sarcastic, sorry for the confusion. I'm pretty sure you could cut your stack trace to about 10%. Your question would be much more readable then. This goes well with the idea of creating "minimal" examples, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using debugger `bankBranch` in `coopMember.personId.bankAccountId.bankBranch` is null which is not making sense at all, as all `bankAccount`s must have `bankBranch` associated with it.

What worked for me is writing the query alittle bit differently.
Left join `bankAccount` on `coopMember.personId.bankAccountId` then do where clause like so

```
    JPAQuery<Integer> query = queryFactory.query()
        .select(coopMember.memberId)
        .distinct()
        .from(coopMember)
        .leftJoin(coopMember.personId.bankAccountId, bankAccount)
        .where(coopMember.voided.isFalse());
    if( bankId != null ){
        query.where(
                bankAccount.isNotNull().and(bankAccount.bankBranch.bankId.eq(bankId))
        );
    }
```

Doing this enabled me to access `bankBranch` without throwing `NullPointerException`(though still i don't understand why accessing `bankBranch` directly like what is in the question is not possible).

Answer (score 10):

I faced a similar issue recently and had to debug through the Q-classes constructors to understand the reason of why a field in the chain was null. Solution lies in the [official documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.2.1/reference/html_single/#d0e2260):

> By default Querydsl initializes only reference properties of the first two levels. In cases where longer initialization paths are required, these have to be annotated in the domain types via com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryInit annotations. QueryInit is used on properties where deep initializations are needed. The following example demonstrates the usage.

```
@Entity
class Event {
    @QueryInit("customer.address")
    Account account;
}

@Entity
class Account {
    Customer customer;
}

@Entity
class Customer {
    String name;
    Address address;
    // ...
}
```

> This example enforces the initialization of the account.customer path, when an Event path is initialized as a root path / variable. The path initialization format supports wildcards as well, e.g. "customer.*" or just "*".

I was hoping to see some global APT option to set the default level or something, but did not find it. So the only solution for me was to "pollute" the entity with "@QueryInit" annotation.

Hope it helps, despite the post is old.

**UPDATE**: In my case `QueryInit("*")` did not work, so I had to use `QueryInit("*.*")` at the "topmost" entity as suggested [here](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2129#issuecomment-420237991). This information is not in the manual, but apparently:

> `*.*` works for multi-level queries while `*` refers to next-level attributes